# EntityFramework generated classes

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4.1, data-annotations

I have an EF model which I have generated using the DataBase First methodology. On the designer, I created a "code generation item" using the DBContext object. This created a template that generated POCO classes for my tables (which I want).

I had been using these same classes to code in the WCF and DataAnnotation attributes in them which worked fine. I saved a copy of this file and if the model got regenerated, I would simply paste the old code into the newly created model generated class and update any new properties.

I tried to take it a step futher. Whenever I change the model, the classes get regenerated and the attributes are lost. What I tried to do was to create a separate folder in my project with the same class names qualifying it by namespace. I basically would copy over any properties that were changed in the generated POCO classes to the other class in the new folder I created and simply added any attributes that I needed. This, though, would be almost doing the same thing as in the second paragraph above. However, if there was is big database model, this could get tedious and prone to errors.

What I want to do is to somehow emulate generating the model without losing the attributes. Yeah, I know --- having my cake and eating it too...

Any ideas?

I tried to add buddy classes, but that didn't work.

The data comes across the wire fine, but after adding the buddy classes as I did below, **the DataAnnotations don't work.**

I thought maybe I would need to change my service method to include the **Customer_Validation** object instead of **Customer** and do the same for the client.

I was about to make this change, but ran into a roadblock on the following code snippet in my service method (**This is even after I changed the definiton of the DbContext** which of course is another code generated class.). There is a design time compile error on p.CustomerID. It doesn't exist.

```
IQueryable<**Customer_Validation**> customer = DbContext.Customers.Where(p => **p.CustomerID** > 0);


 public DbSet<**Customer_Validation**> Customers { get; set; }
```

**What am I missing in order to get the DataAnnotations to work? Your help is very much appreciated :)**

**I have the following for my Customer class.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using DataAnnotationsExtensions;

namespace YeagerTechModel
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(Customer_Validation))]
    public partial class Customer
    {

    }

    public partial class Customer_Validation
    {
        [Serializable]
        [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
        public class Customer1
        {
            public Customer1()
            {
                this.Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
            }

            [DataMember]
            public short CustomerID { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [Required]
            [StringLength(50)]
            [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
            [Email]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Must have a minimum length of 3.")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string Company { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Must have a minimum length of 3.")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Must have a minimum length of 3.")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Must have a minimum length of 3.")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string Address1 { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [StringLength(50)]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string Address2 { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Must have a minimum length of 3.")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string City { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [StringLength(2, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Must have a length of 2.")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string State { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [StringLength(10)]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Zip")]
            public string Zip { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [StringLength(12)]
            [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
            [RegularExpression(@"^\s*([\(]?)\[?\s*\d{3}\s*\]?[\)]?\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone")]
            public string HomePhone { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [StringLength(12)]
            [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
            [RegularExpression(@"^\s*([\(]?)\[?\s*\d{3}\s*\]?[\)]?\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone")]
            public string CellPhone { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [StringLength(100)]
            [DataType(DataType.Url)]
            [Url]
            public string Website { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [StringLength(50)]
            [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
            [Email]
            public string IMAddress { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**My web service method is as follows:**

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities();

            DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            IQueryable<Customer> customer = DbContext.Customers.Where(p => p.CustomerID > 0);

            CloseConnection(DbContext);

            return customer;
        }
```

**My client method makes a call to the above service method with the following:**

```
IEnumerable<YeagerTechModel.Customer> customerList = db.GetCustomers();

                    return View(new GridModel<YeagerTechModel.Customer>
                    {
                        Data = customerList
                    });
```

**My View is as follows:**

```
@model Telerik.Web.Mvc.GridModel<YeagerTechModel.Customer>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer Index";
}
<h2>
    Customer Index</h2>
@(  Html.Telerik().Grid<YeagerTechModel.Customer>(Model.Data)
      .Name("Customers")
            .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(o => o.CustomerID)
                                            .RouteKey("CustomerID"))
                .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text).ImageHtmlAttributes(new { style = "margin-left:0" }))
      .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.CustomerID).Hidden(true);
                columns.Command(commands =>
                {
                    commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text);
                }).Width(200).Title("Command");
                columns.Bound(o => o.Email).Width(200).Filterable(false);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Company).Width(200).Filterable(false);
                columns.Bound(o => o.FirstName).Width(100).Title("FName").Filterable(false);
                columns.Bound(o => o.LastName).Width(100).Title("LName").Filterable(false);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Address1).Width(200).Title("Addr1").Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Address2).Width(100).Title("Addr2").Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
                columns.Bound(o => o.City).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.State).Width(40).Title("ST");
                columns.Bound(o => o.Zip).Width(60);
                columns.Bound(o => o.HomePhone).Width(120).Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
                columns.Bound(o => o.CellPhone).Width(120).Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Website).Width(100).Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
                columns.Bound(o => o.IMAddress).Width(100).Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
                columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").ReadOnly(true).Width(120).Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
                columns.Bound(o => o.UpdatedDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").ReadOnly(true).Width(120).Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
            }).DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                dataBinding.Ajax()
                        .Insert("_InsertAjaxEditing", "Customer")
                        .Update("_SaveAjaxEditing", "Customer"))
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Scrollable()
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the T4 template to include the attributes when it generates the classes.

You might also consider using Data Transfer Objects and annotating them instead of your entities.  I am currently working on a project using EF 4.1 (db first) and WCF, and I use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map between my DTOs and entities.  My service api takes and returns DTOs, which are then mapped in the repository to entities.  This allows me to shape the data exposed by the service when I don't want it to look exactly as it is stored in the database.

For more discussion on the pros and cons of using DTOs, see this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236638.aspx#id0080022).